# como passar um item de uma listview para um textview na mesma Activity

Tags: android, listview, textview

Minha dúvida é com relação a captura de uma informação em uma `ListView` no Android e colar a mesma informação em uma `TextView`.

**Exemplo:** eu criei uma `ListView` de frutas e quero que ao clicar em uma fruta da lista o nome desta fruta apareça neste `TextView`.

Comment: vc tem algum código já feito? poderia colocar ele na pergunta? é em java ou kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

`seuListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        itemSelecionado = lista.get(i);
        seuTextView.setText(itemSelecionado);
        return false;
    }
});`

Essa "lista", é a lista que está populando seu `ListView` (List, ArrayList, etc)

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            //aqui vc irá fazer a acao com o click pegando uma posicao da sua lista, e setando o texto
            mText = mListaFrutas[position]; 
        }
    });
```